# Some troubles on mysql 5.7 json feature

Tags: mysql, json

Table net_card is used to store the net card information with json type ,here is my table :

```
`net_card` (
  `serial_number` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `data` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`serial_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

One of data of the  table net_card is:

serial_number: 12GLW02

```
data: {"netCard": [
{"ip": "172.16.14.67", "mac": "f8:bc:12:41:9e:a4", "bond": "no", "name": "em1", "serialNumber": "12GLW02"}, 
{"ip": "NULL", "mac": "f8:bc:12:41:9e:a5", "bond": "no", "name": "em2", "serialNumber": "12GLW02"}, 
{"ip": "NULL", "mac": "f8:bc:12:41:9e:a6", "bond": "no", "name": "em3", "serialNumber": "12GLW02"}, 
{"ip": "NULL", "mac": "f8:bc:12:41:9e:a7", "bond": "no", "name": "em4", "serialNumber": "12GLW02"}, 
{"ip": "127.0.0.1", "mac": "NULL", "bond": "no", "name": "lo", "serialNumber": "12GLW02"}]}
```

well ,i wanna  get the ipList and its value is not "NULL",

I use the sql `select data->'$[0].netCard[*].ip' from net_card limit 1` to get the result that contains "NULL";the result is :

```
["172.16.14.67", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "127.0.0.1"]
```

And I wanna get `["172.16.14.67","127.0.0.1"]`
How could I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string replace function for this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(data->'$.netCard[*].ip', '"NULL", ', "") FROM net_card ;
```

But it's definitely not the best solution. This one only works if the `NULL`s are not at the end (because of the `,`).